# Future proofing code

Tags: productivity, programming-practices

Where I work developers are always telling me that "I added this just in case for the future" or "I think it's a good idea to do this because they'll probably want it some day". I think it's great that they're proactive in trying to anticipate future changes but I can't help thinking that it's unnecessary and risks writing code that may never be needed and therefore unproductive (I also think that some developers just want to try out something new for the sake of it). Are the arguments for future proofing invalid if you just write good, clean organised code?

Comment: I think that the only futureproof code is...well whitespace. :)

Comment: "Just in time, not just in case".

Comment: @edem I disagree, that language is no different than others for future-proofing...  (^_—)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Well first of all, there are some things that need clarification:

- Future proofing is **not** adding stuff.
- Future proofing is making sure you can **easily** add code/features without breaking existing functionality.

This means is that writing "future proof" code, is ensuring that the code is written in a loose coupled manner, sufficiently abstract, but also code that does not completely hide abstraction levels, so there's always a way to go to the lower abstraction levels if necessary.

Writing future proof code is an art by itself and is tightly coupled with SOLID practices for component versioning, separation of concerns, layering and abstractness of functionality. Future proofing has **nothing** to do with adding features ahead of time, but with making sure you can add features in the future in a **non breaking** manner, through the good design of existing code/libraries.

My 2c

Comment: This and @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen answer regarding tests combined would be the perfect answer.

Comment: I've seen it many times, "ho we will add this because one day we will need it", either the day never comes, or when it comes well, you are stuck with a data structure or program structure that does not really fit the actual need when it finally arises.  The right way then would be to take out the old stuff and build anew but usually the tendency to future-proof like this is often associated with a strong disdain to throw away code that was already done no matter if it is good or not.  Such teams usually tend to onion design, masking bugs from a layers with yet another layer.

Comment: Future proofing may not be adding *features* but certainly you can be adding code. One technique is to add safety checks and explicitly disallow any undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 20):

It is important to realise that making code **future proof**, and writing code **in case it is needed in the future** are two very different things.  The former is crucial to a good application, the lesser is usually not good coding practice.

- For me, future proofing the code, is writing it in a way that it will be able to interact with evolving technologies.  This involves modularising your code, so that each part of your application can interact independently of the language and technology of the application as a whole.  A good example of this would be using XML or JSON to pass data between different parts of the application.  However technology evolves, it is very likely that it will always be able to read XML and JSON.
- Similar to the above, exposing a part of your application via a SOAP or REST API achieves a similar thing.  Whatever technologies evolve, you will not necessarily need to re-write every part of the application because new technologies will still be able to communicate with old.
- On the point of writing code *in case it is needed*, I think that it is very dangerous as the code is likely to have little or no testing.

So, by all means, make code future proof (NASA still send spaceships up using Fortran), but dont write code 'just in case'.

Comment: +1 for the distinction between 'future proof' and 'in case it's needed for the future'

Comment: Sound design advice.  The only thing missing from this is a clear statement that "future proof" is merely a meaningless buzz-phrase that means "reasonably well-designed".

Answer (score 19):

Do not write code that will not be used for a long time.  It will be useless as it most likely will not fit the needs at that time (which you by definition do not know yet).

Make the code robust against unexpected problem situations allowing for graceful recovery or fail-fast, but do not write code for possible future uses.

A good way to ensure that, is to use test driven design and development.  Test cases are derived from the specification and use cases.  All code must make a test pass.  Unneeded code should not be written.  By doing it this way it is simple to determine if it is needed or not.

Comment: +1: It's so hard to predict the future.  Simply using good design -- and calling it "good design" -- is better than pretending to predict the future.

Answer (score 11):

Think about how many time you have enabled a piece of code down the line in a production environment and thought, "Thank god I wrote that 2 years ago!".

Code should be modifiable / extendable easily. Don't add code that isn't immediately necessary, because this gives a very false sense of security and wastes dev/test resources in a world of changing requirements.

Comment: Are you suggesting "Thank god I wrote that 2 years ago!" is rare?  In my experience it's never happened, but perhaps that's just me.

Comment: It is a very rare occurence - because code bases that remain solid without 2 years / predicting changes 2 years away are very hard to come by.

Comment: Well, I've actually had quite a few "Thanks god I wrote that a year ago" moments. I'm more clever than I think was.

Comment: @Falcon care to elaborate on these moments?  Would be quite interesting to know which ones you got right.

Answer (score 8):

A lot of the other answers address kind of larger design issues, or are rather abstract. If you think in terms of what will happen in the future you can define some clear techniques to help *future-proof* the code.

Primarily think that in the future somebody will try to add a feature to the code, or will attempt to reuse your code somewhere else.  They may also try to fix a feature in the code.  Obviously just having good clean code is a required starting point, but there are also some specific techniques that can be done.

**Defensive Programming**: Do input checking beyond what you current application actually needs. Whenever you call APIs be sure sure to check that their input is something that you would expect. In the future people will be mixing new versions of code together, so the scope of errors and API returns will change from what it is now.

**Elliminate Undefined Behaviour**: A lot of code has behaviour which just kind of evolves from nowhere. Certain combinations of input lead to certain output which nobody really intended, but just so happens. Now inevitably somebody will rely on that behaviour, but nobody will know about it since it isn't defined. Anybody attempting to change the behaviour in the future will inadvertently break things. Use safety checks now and try to remove/block all undefined uses of the code.

**Automated Test Suite**: I'm sure you can find volumes written about the need for unit tests. In reference to future proofing however this is a critical point in allowing somebody to refactor the code. Refactoring is essential to maintaining clean code, but if lack a good suite of tests you can't safely refactor.

**Isolation and Segregation**: Encapsulation and proper modularization is a good design principle, but you need to go beyond that. You'll often find that you need to use a library, or API, or product, which may have a questionable future. Maybe due to quality concerns, licensing problems, or continued development by the authors. In these cases take extra time to put a layer between you and this code. Slice down the API to just what you need so the coupling is very low to allow easier replacement in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Good, clean, well-organized code **is** future-proof in the sense that it makes changes and additions easier to implement correctly.

Answer (score 6):

**YAGNI** = [You Aren't Gonna Need It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Your instincts are correct: their code is superfluous, adds a burden of maintenance and testing, and wastes time on things that don't have a concrete business value.

See Also: [Gold Plating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating_%28analogy%29).

Answer (score 5):

"Future Proof" at best means "loosely-coupled design".  80% of the time people mean "flexible" when they say "future proof".  Sometimes they say it to try and sound cool.  But at least they're delivering something on time that works.

"Future Proof" at worst is meaningless.  20% of the time, it's an excuse to waste time researching alternative technologies instead of simply delivering something.  They're not delivering anything (or what they're delivering is too complex for the problem at hand.)

There are two edge cases.

1. Unfailing foresight.  One actually **can** predict the future accurately.  In this case, please apply this powerful foresight to future proof the code.  Better, apply the unfailing foresight to predict market trends and retire early and stop coding.
2. One  is "driving" the future.  That is, one has some new technology ready to deploy in the future that will require a rewrite of the thing being delivered right now.  That's weird that one is not deploying this cool future thing first.

   We must deliver project "A", knowing that project "B" will lead to an immediate rewrite of "A".  In this case only, we might be able to future proof "A".

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the title of the question, and sticking the main point about "putting stuff in because somebody might want it some day"...

The answer is NO.  Never.  Don't write a stitch of code you don't need today.  Here's why:

1. The program is now more complicated than it needs to be.
2. You may never need the feature, so you've wasted your time.
3. You don't know what the requirements for the feature will be if anyone ever asks for it in the future.  So you'll have to figure it out and modify it anyways.

I think the first point is the most important.  If you've ever worked with a system that's riddled with generic code for different customers, or full of feature bloat with stuff you don't need then you know just how much extra time and effort it takes to maintain or extend the functionality because of that.  So avoid at all costs.